# When converting a master_data to only master what happens to all the search indexes on Kubernetes node?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 6 node master-data K8s cluster. I want to change it to 3 master and 3 data nodes exclusively.
I found documentation on how to change role but nowhere was mentioned what happens to all the indexes on the newly changed master node once reallocation is done.
Does K8s remove all the now obsolete data or just ignores it and leaves it in .

I know it sounds silly but I have not been able to answer this confidently on any material I found online.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the role of nodes in a Kubernetes cluster, such as changing some nodes to be master nodes and others to be data nodes, the actual data stored on the nodes is not affected by Kubernetes itself.

In the case of a master-data K8s cluster, the master nodes typically do not store any data; they are responsible for managing the cluster state and coordinating operations between the data nodes. So if you change some nodes from being master nodes to being data nodes, the data that was previously stored on the other data nodes will still be present on those nodes after the reallocation.

However, if you are using a data storage solution that is integrated with Kubernetes, such as a persistent volume or a StatefulSet, you may need to take additional steps to ensure that the data is properly migrated to the new data nodes. This will depend on the specifics of your storage solution and how you have configured it.

In general, it's always a good idea to make backups of your data before making any changes to your Kubernetes cluster or its nodes, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in kubernetes the master node data like **settings** ,**manifests** and **metadata** about the cluster will be stored in **etcd**, which is a **distributed key-value** storage in kubernetes. **Etcd** is designed to ensure that the data is always **consistent across all nodes** in the cluster, including the **master** nodes and **data** nodes as well. So , if you convert a **master node** to **data(worker) node** then the **etcd** will handle the **replication and distribution** of that master node data to the other active master nodes in the cluster.

In case you are using the storage volumes for your application in kubernetes like **Persistent volumes(PV)**, **Storage classes**, **Configmaps** and **Secrets** then you need to ensure that the data is **backed up properly** before migrating. There are so many ways to back up the volumes, Taking **snapshots** is one of them.

To know more about **volumesnapshots** refer to this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/)